# Is there any simple way to convert html text to image without cutting things that are outside of viewport

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've tried using some html2image or puppeteer screenshot but every time it cuts page to viewport.
I've tried also converting html to pdf but I'cant find any simple way to convert that pdf to image.
I want to convert html text from string variable or in puppeteer screenshot to image file [png,gif,jpg]

```html
<html><body>Some Text</body></html>
```

OR maybe if you know how to embed pdf (or html) in discord message to show it like image. Not only to download (discord bot)

[I'm thinking about this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LK2zC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```js
    await page.setContent(source)
    const element = await page.$("body")
    const buffer = await element.screenshot({
        path: "./tmp.png",
        omitBackground: false,
        ...screeshotArgs
    });
    await page.close();
```